# MVC form post to refresh an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, refresh

I have a MVC 2 based website with a contact form that has an anti-spam CAPTCHA image on it.

After completing most the form, the user decides he/she cannot read the image, so I have a button that allows the user to refresh the page with a different image.  This causes a full page reload (which I am fine with).

I want the entire page to load with the existing data to remain and just display a different image instead.

So how do I call an action that retains the values and does not trigger validation?

Now the problem that I have is...
1. How to I allow the perform the post without triggering validation?
2. How do I maintain the form values?

I am not interested in AJAX solutions and I am not interested in reCAPTCHA.

Thanks.
Dan.

**UPDATE - think I have a solution - feedback welcomed!**

```
// All buttons on a form are post to the same action method so read in the value of the submit buttons to take appropriate action.
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult sendlink(BusinessLinkModel linkToCreate, string button)
{
    // Validation logic
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linkToCreate.BusinessTitle)) ModelState.AddModelError("BusinessTitle", "Business title is required.");

    string submitButtonName = button;

    // If we want to "reload" the captcha image, then we'll clear all the errors, do nothing with the data but update the session so the image
    // is re-generated appropriately.
    if (submitButtonName == "reload")
    {
        // Clear the errors - hacktastic!
        foreach (ModelState item in this.ModelState.Values.ToList())
        {
            item.Errors.Clear();
        }

        ResetSecurityCode();
    }

    return View();
}

// This is the image url i.e. /home/GenerateSecurityImage
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GenerateSecurityImage()
{
    string code = Session["CAPTCHA_Contact"] == null ? ResetSecurityCode() : Session["CAPTCHA_Contact"].ToString(); 

    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    GenerateImage(code, 180, 70).Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    Response.End();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Obviously in my final version I wouldn't perform validation checks then clear them - the validation checks would be performed only if it were the actual final submit button.  Tiny bit hacky at the point I am looping round clearing all errors - that's the bit I am nervous about - i.e. in case of nested forms or fancy mvc things I don't know about.  Also, I have only been using MVC for a week so i'm a self confessed n00b!

Answer (score 0):

If you do recapture, you have to create a special action for that

```
public ActionResult Recapture(Model m)
{
   // reinit capture

   return View("yourForm", m);
}
```

yourForm - form you originally display to user. If m is initialized with some values, they would be displayed on form. If Model.IsValid is not called, it would not cause validation.

Comment: Well I think that would still trigger validation as the Model will be annotated.  But I do like how you pass the data back! GENIUS.  I will answer back in a moment - would like to get feedback on how hacky it is.